# How do I Set XmlArrayItem Element name for a List<Custom> implementation?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I want to create a custom XML structure as follows:

```
<Hotels>
    <Hotel />
</Hotels>
```

I've created an implementation of `List` just to be able to do this. My code is as follows:

```
[XmlRootAttribute(ElementName="Hotels")]
public class HotelList: List<HotelBasic>
```

Because the class that List holds is not named `Hotel` but `HotelBasic` my xml is like

```
<Hotels>
   <HotelBasic />
</Hotels>
```

How do I fix this without having to implement `ISerializable` or `IEnumerable`?

Comment: Do you want serialize or deserialize?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming you are using `XmlSerializer`, if all you want to do is change how your `HotelBasic` class is serialized, you can use `XmlTypeAttribute`:

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "Hotel")]
public class HotelBasic
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When used with your `HotelList` class it will be serialized as:

```
<Hotels xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Hotel>
    <Name>One</Name>
  </Hotel>
  <Hotel>
    <Name>Two</Name>
  </Hotel>
</Hotels>
```

Answer (score 35):

```
[XmlArray("Hotels")]
[XmlArrayItem(typeof(Hotel), ElementName="Hotel")]
public HotelList[] Messages { get; set; }
```

should produce:

```
<Hotels>
    <Hotel />
    <Hotel />
</Hotels>
```

---

```
[XmlRoot("Hotels")]
public class HotelList : IXmlSerializable
{
    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        this.Hotels = XDocument.Load(reader)
                               .Select(h => new Hotel { Name = (string)h.Attribute("name") }
                               .ToList();
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to use List<HotelBasic>, not HotelBasic[]

Comment: @odyodyodys: 1. XmlSerializer supports only array. 2. You asked for `IEnumerable<T>`, array implements it. 3. You do not want `List<T>` because it's a expendable container, but list in xml is *final*. 4. You can create list calling `ToList()`.

Comment: I am using `List`s methods like Find and lots more. It would be just pain to reimplement `List`

Comment: @odyodyodys: You can call `ToList().Find(...)`, or use not XmlSerializer and set of attributes, but mark only root element and implement `IXmlSerializable` for custom structure.

Comment: @odyodyodys: I've updated my answer how to implement `IXmlSerializable`.

Comment: @Marc: I prefer LINQ to XML option as giving maximum flexibility in complex scenarios. Also saves from headache from infinite attribute decoration.

Answer (score 8):

I think madd0 shows the simplest option for you here, but just for completeness... personally I don't recommend the "serialize the list as the root object" - for various reasons (including: I've seen those attributes not work on at least on platform - might have been CF or SL, can't remember). Instead, I always advise using a custom root type:

```
[XmlRoot("Hotels")]
public class HotelResult // or something similar
{
    [XmlElement("Hotel")]
    public List<HotelBasic> Hotels { get { return hotel; } }

    private readonly List<HotelBasic> hotels = new List<HotelBasic>();
}
```

This will have the same xml structure, and allows greater flexibility (you can add other attributes / elements to the root), and doesn't bake `List<T>` into your type model (prefer encapsulation over inheritance, etc).