# Serialize Class to XML issue with XmlRoot Declaration

Tags: c#, .net, xml, winforms

Im serializing my class to XML. I have an issue with the root element of one of my classes is NOT being named properly.

**The complete XML structure should look like the following.**

```
<Workflow>
  <Name>My Workflow</Name>
  <Description />
  <Modules>
    <Module Name="Intro" MenuText="IntroText" />
  </Modules>
</Workflow>
```

**However Im getting this result**

```
<Workflow>
  <Name>My Workflow</Name>
  <Description />
  <Modules>
    <WorkflowModule Name="Intro" MenuText="IntroText" />
  </Modules>
</Workflow>
```

I want the element "WorkflowModule" to be called "Module" however the problem is that I already have another class called Module. So to get around this problem I called it a WorkflowModule and put a class XmlRoot() declartion like so;

```
[XmlRoot("Module")]
public class WorkflowModule
{...}
```

But when I serialize the Workflow class it still comes up with WorkflowModule.

Here are my 2 classes classes;

```
[XmlRoot("Workflow")]
public class Workflow
{

    private string _name;
    private string _description;
    private List<WorkflowModule> _modules = new List<WorkflowModule>();



    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public String Name
    {
        get {  }
        set {  }
    }


    [XmlElement("Description")]
    public String Description
    {
        get {  }
        set {  }
    }


    [XmlArrayItem(typeof(WorkflowModule))]
    public List<WorkflowModule> Modules
    {
        get { }
        set { }
    }
}








[XmlRoot("Module")]
public class WorkflowModule
{

    private string _name;
    private string _menu_text;


    public WorkflowModule()
    {
    }


    [XmlAttribute("Name")]
    public String Name
    {
        get { }
        set { }

    }


    [XmlAttribute("MenuText")]
    public String MenuText
    {
        get { }
        set { }

    }

}
```

}

Comment: xml document can have only one Root

Comment: so where I define XmlRoot() for WorkflowModule class is there a way to serialize as another name ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the element name within `XmlArrayItem` attrubute:

```
[XmlArrayItem(typeof(WorkflowModule), ElementName = "Module")]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to control it as defined in this duplicate post [How do I Set XmlArrayItem Element name for a List<Custom> implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254264/how-do-i-set-xmlarrayitem-element-name-for-a-listcustom-implementation)

These attribute control serialize from the this object's perspective as it transverses nested objects

```
[XmlArray("RootArrayElementNameGoesHere")]
[XmlArrayItem(typeof(Workflow), ElementName="ArrayItemElementNameGoesHere")]
public List<WorkflowModule> Modules
```

This attribute redefining the element name but can be overwritten with the local [XmlArrayItem] or [XmlElement] attributes to provides local override from the owning objects serialization

```
[XmlType(TypeName = "UseThisElementNameInsteadOfClassName")]
public class WorkflowModule
```

This attribute is only honored when its the direct object being serialized

```
[XmlRoot("UseThisElementNameWhenItIsTheRoot")]
public class WorkflowModule
```